# bigcommerce stencil checkout - add custom JS

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce

I am trying to add a custom JS on the  of the checkout page using the Stencil platform. I download the cornerstone theme into my computer using the stencil-cli solution. I can see that there is a checkout.html inside the templates folder but, any change I made on that page is not reflected on the store checkout page. Any idea ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the checkout.html page isn't actually used to render checkout. You can see more details on what can be customized here: https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/checkout-header-customization

To insert JS to the checkout page, you can use the google analytics box under Advanced Settings > Web Analytics. This will cause it to show in checkout.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the JS to the checkout_express.html file, this is where I made my JS modifications to hide shipping options based on the currently logged in user's group.